# url rewriting using .htaccess need guide

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am creating website (currently on localhost), I have a page for movies named Movie.php which has an get variable that access the required movie like this

`Website/Movie.php?MovieID=2267998`

when I rewrite url, it shows me error that page not found, I just simply wanted to show link like that

`Website/Movie/2267998`

like imdb, that dont show and get variable, what should I have to do, should I need to create different files for each movie, remember I also don't want to show any type of extension .htm, .html, .php, how is this possible, or should i create a temporary file, i can't understand how to do this. I can't find my desired solution on stackoverflow

Comment: Can you show your current rule?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Shazi/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Movie\.php\?MovieID=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ Movie/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^Movie/(\d+)/?$ Movie.php?MovieID=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/Shazi/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```